# Is there a way to iterate through the values of two columns using a for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

So I am trying to change the values of a column in a dataframe based on the values in another column

this is what I tried

```
features = ['p', 'q', 'r']
for x in features:
    # Calculate mean without outliers
    Z =3
    q['zscore'] = zscore(q[x])
    mean_ = q[(q['zscore'] > -Z) & (q['zscore'] < Z)][x].mean()
    a =[x, 'zscore']
    for y, z in a:
        if y < 4:
            z = np.nan
```

With this, hoping that y represents the values in x and z represents the values in 'zscore'
please help me out.

Comment: You have a list of only two items. Why do you need a loop?

Comment: It's not a list, it's a DataFrame with over 30 features, I only selected the features I want edit.

Comment: Hmm, no. `len(a) == 2`, for `y, z in a` won't work...  and you've not shown what `q` is, and `x` is always a single character string

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `zip` function.
Here is an example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

for x, y in zip(a,b):
    print(x, y)
```

**Output**

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Comment: Let me edit this and implement it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Read the two columns into a zip function and call your for loop on it.

I think that's what the answer  suggests too.

Comment: I did that already and it worked. Thank you so much.